# How to (securely) trigger actions on Raspberry Pi from IFTTT?

Tags: home-automation

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 with a breadboard that's got an RF transmitter & receiver.  I can control 8 Etekcity outlets using Siri/Homekit via homebridge-commander/pilight, however I would like to take advantage of various IFTTT triggers to be able to control my 8 outlets automatically.

These RF outlets are dumb.  The only way to turn them on/off is either via RF signal or a physical button.  There's no option to talk to the outlets via any other means.  I have a shell script I made for homebridge-commander that can control the outlets via `etekcity_control.sh outlet_name powerstate set true/false`.

I discovered that homebridge-ifttt only supports communication from RPi to IFTTT.  I want to go the other way around.  I want things on IFTTT to trigger the RPi to take actions (e.g. turn on or off an RF outlet).

The best solution would meet all of these criteria:

- secure (no exposed ports and no sending of executable commands)
- fast/responsive & reliable
- automations can be enabled/disabled from iPhone from anywhere
- small disk/processor/memory footprint
- requires only installs & config, i.e. no custom coding
- allows me to use any trigger available on IFTTT

(Plus, it would be really convenient if when I buy new outlets, I don't have to setup a third config file in addition to homebridge and homebridge-commander.)

I googled for options this past weekend, but had difficulty wading through all the flood of RPi->IFTTT solutions that don't support IFTTT->RPi.

Comment: This should be possible using webhooks. Here is a tutorial I found where something similar is achieved with the help of node-red: https://dev.to/krusenas/controlling-gadgets-with-google-home-ifttt-and-node-red-3ea2

Comment: NodeRed looks really cool! I will definitely be checking that and webhook relay out!  Thanks!

Comment: I should even be able to replace my Stringify flows with this!

Comment: @oh-dae-su - That blog post had just what I needed (webhookrelay). It meets all of my wants except the ability to enable/disable (out of the box), though I have some ideas on how to implement that part. If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: I am glad, that the comment was helpful. I have posted it as answer. :-) Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have a bidrectional communication between IFTTT and Raspberry Pi you can utilize the [webhooks technology](https://ifttt.com/maker_webhooks).

Here is a [tutorial](https://dev.to/krusenas/controlling-gadgets-with-google-home-ifttt-and-node-red-3ea2) I found where something similar to your objective is achieved with the help of node-red. To be precise, in node-red the [webhook-relay](https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-webhookrelay) is used for the connection to IFTTT.

Comment: Been using webhook relay and node red for *so* much! Thanks again!

Comment: :-) same here... Glad you found it helpful.